# Spring Integration JMS MessageDrivenChannelAdapter connection status

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-jms

With Spring 5.3.29, how can I detect that a `MessageDriveChannelAdapter` **is** connected to JMS without receiving a message.

Currently, I have;

```
IntegrationFlows.from(
   Jms
      .messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
      .destination(myDestination)
      .errorChannel(myErrorChannel)
      .configureListenerContainer(c -> {
         c.errorHandler(...);
         c.exceptionListener(...);
   })
   .handle(...)
   .get();
```

By implementing the `ErrorHandler` and `ExceptionListener` I can alert that we are not connected. I could implement "clear alert" logic in the `handle()`, but I want to "clear" without getting a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event like that in Spring JMS, nor JMS spec by itself. And probably there is indeed no reason in it: when you receive a message in the `handle()`, that's definitely an indicator that connection to JMS broker was OK. If connection fails, that `exceptionListener()` would do that trick.

You can do that "clear" logic in the `ChannelInterceptor` before that `handle()`.

See `intercept()` DSL operator:

```
/**
 * Add one or more {@link ChannelInterceptor} implementations
 * to the current {@link #currentMessageChannel}, in the given order, after any interceptors already registered.
 * @param interceptorArray one or more {@link ChannelInterceptor}s.
 * @return the current {@link BaseIntegrationFlowDefinition}.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if one or more null arguments are provided
 * @since 5.3
 */
public B intercept(ChannelInterceptor... interceptorArray) {
```